# max min width in css

Tags: html, css

I have following input boxes.

[image]

I reduced their width to align them in-line and it looks good in full sized window,Now problem occurs when i do narrow screen.

It looks really bad while doing narrow screen.

**A look-**

[image]

I tried these input boxes to get a new line with setting up `max-width`.

**In code**-

I am using input as-

For price Ex. Vat-

```
  <input type="text" style="width:85%;max-width:85%;" id="Order" maxlength = "10" name="PriceExVat"   onkeypress="validate(event)"/>
```

But it doesn't get a new line while doing narrow screen.

I want this desired responsive layout for these input blocks-

[image]

Comment: How did you style them? (CSS code)

Answer (score 8):

Do a media query and make them block elements -

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 0px) {
 input[type="text"] {
  display:block;
 }
}
```

Comment: You want to make the wrapping element `display:block`, because the label has to come with the input to a new line, not only the input. But the principle is good.

Comment: @Vineet,I think this will do it for all existing input elements, But i want this to be done on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You must use `min-width` for preventing elements from shrinking after a particular width.

Replace `max-width` with `min-width` in your-code and try again. Also you might want to specify `max-width: nPixels px;` to prevent the text-boxes from occupying 85% width when on full screen.

Comment: These are not overlapping now when i set it with min-width, But it's not taking a new line.

Comment: what method are you using to align the elements?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have added `display: inline;` try `display: inline-block;` this may solve the problem.